# Snowflake proc issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure, execution

I am having issue while executing below proc in snowflake.

Here is the code.

"**

> > create or replace procedure test_0916() returns string not null   language javascript   execute as owner   as   $$   try   {
> > var sqlquery=" ";
> > var outcome=" ";
> > var x=" ";`
>
> `sql_command =`select salary from EMPLOYEES where employee_id=8`;
> var rs=snowflake.execute({sqlText:sql_command});
> rs.next();/* Here not using while loop because it returns only one value*/
> x=rs.getcolumnValue(1);
> sqlquery=fltConvUomPK;                     }
>
> catch (err) {
> return "Error: " + err;
> }"
> return  sqlquery;
> $$;

**"

When I am trying to execute the proc as below

> Blockquote

call test_0916();
I am getting below error.

Error: TypeError: rs.getcolumnValue is not a function

Comment: Function name is case sensitive, Replace getcolumnValue to getColumnValue in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The method name is getColumnValue()

Can you check the spelling?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-api.html#getColumnValue

Comment: Thank You its helps me a lot